# Trying to convert non-ARC 'CallHandler' (call blocker) to ARC encounter problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, call, block

Problem 1:
I found the code on github, I managed to import it to my ARC project and set a non-ARC flag, all works well.
What I'm trying to do is convert the code to ARC so working on it will be much easier.

In trying to fix,

> Cast of C pointer type 'CFStringRef' ..... requires a bridge cast

Before: `NSString *notifyname=(NSString *)name;`
After: `NSString *notifyname=(NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(name);`
- I got rid of the error.

Then,

> No known class method for selector 'sharedMessageCenter' No known
>   class method for selector 'incomingMessageWithId:' No known class
>   method for selector 'messageType' No known class method for selector
>   'canonicalFormat'

Problem 2:
Beside, I cannot make it block all phone calls in background.
When app is active: I can block all phone calls and disconnect specific phone numbers,
When app is in background: I cannot block all phone calls, only specific phone numbers.

P.S. - Any idea hot to write s 'stop' function?

Code is:

CallHandler.h:

```
//
//  CallHandler.h
//  PhoneCallBlock
//
//  Created by Hui Li on 12-5-11.
//  Copyright (c) 2012年 hust. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


#define     kCTIndicatorsSignalStrengthNotification         @"kCTIndicatorsSignalStrengthNotification"
#define     kCTRegistrationStatusChangedNotification        @"kCTRegistrationStatusChangedNotification"
#define     kCTRegistrationDataStatusChangedNotification    @"kCTRegistrationDataStatusChangedNotification"
#define     kCTRegistrationCellChangedNotification          @"kCTRegistrationCellChangedNotification"
#define     kCTIndicatorRadioTransmitNotification           @"kCTIndicatorRadioTransmitNotification"


@interface CallHandler : NSObject
{

}


+ (void)start;


static void callback(CFNotificationCenterRef center, void *observer, CFStringRef name, const void *object, CFDictionaryRef userInfo);
static void signalHandler(int sigraised);



@end
```

CallHandler.m:

```
//
//  CallHandler.m
//  PhoneCallBlock
//
//  Created by Hui Li on 12-5-11.
//  Copyright (c) 2012年 hust. All rights reserved.
//

#import "CallHandler.h"

@implementation CallHandler

extern NSString* const kCTSMSMessageReceivedNotification;
extern NSString* const kCTSMSMessageReplaceReceivedNotification;
extern NSString* const kCTSIMSupportSIMStatusNotInserted;
extern NSString* const kCTSIMSupportSIMStatusReady; 



typedef struct __CTCall CTCall;
extern NSString *CTCallCopyAddress(void*, CTCall *);
extern void CTCallDisconnect(CTCall*);

void* CTSMSMessageSend(id server,id msg);
typedef struct __CTSMSMessage CTSMSMessage;  
NSString *CTSMSMessageCopyAddress(void *, CTSMSMessage *);  
NSString *CTSMSMessageCopyText(void *, CTSMSMessage *);


int CTSMSMessageGetRecordIdentifier(void * msg);
NSString * CTSIMSupportGetSIMStatus();  
NSString * CTSIMSupportCopyMobileSubscriberIdentity(); 

id  CTSMSMessageCreate(void* unknow/*always 0*/,NSString* number,NSString* text);
void * CTSMSMessageCreateReply(void* unknow/*always 0*/,void * forwardTo,NSString* text);


id CTTelephonyCenterGetDefault(void);
void CTTelephonyCenterAddObserver(id,id,CFNotificationCallback,NSString*,void*,int);
void CTTelephonyCenterRemoveObserver(id,id,NSString*,void*);
int CTSMSMessageGetUnreadCount(void); 

#pragma mark - Call Block Methods

+ (void)start
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    // Initialize listener by adding CT Center observer implicit
    id ct = CTTelephonyCenterGetDefault();
    CTTelephonyCenterAddObserver( ct, NULL, callback,NULL,NULL,
                                 CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorHold);

    // Handle Interrupts
    sig_t oldHandler = signal(SIGINT, signalHandler);
    if (oldHandler == SIG_ERR)
    {
        NSLog(@"Could not establish new signal handler");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Run loop lets me catch notifications
    NSLog(@"Starting run loop and watching for notification.\n");
    CFRunLoopRun();

    // Shouldn't ever get here. Bzzzt
    NSLog(@"Unexpectedly back from CFRunLoopRun()!\n");
    [pool release];
}

static void callback(CFNotificationCenterRef center, void *observer, CFStringRef name, const void *object, CFDictionaryRef userInfo)
{
    NSString *notifyname=(NSString *)name;

    if ([notifyname isEqualToString:@"kCTCallStatusChangeNotification"])//电话
    {
        NSDictionary *info = (NSDictionary*)userInfo;

        NSString *state=[info[@"kCTCallStatus"] stringValue];
        if ([state isEqualToString:@"5"])//disconnect
            NSLog(@"未接:%@",state);

    }
    else if ([notifyname isEqualToString:@"kCTCallIdentificationChangeNotification"])
    {
        NSDictionary *info = (NSDictionary *)userInfo;
        CTCall *call = (CTCall *)info[@"kCTCall"];
        NSString *caller = CTCallCopyAddress(NULL, call);
        NSLog(@"电话号码:%@",caller);
        if ([caller isEqualToString:@"1800123456"])
        {
            //disconnect this call
            NSLog(@"挂雷冰");
            CTCallDisconnect(call);
        }

    }
    else if ([notifyname isEqualToString:@"kCTMessageReceivedNotification"])//收到短信
    {
        /*
         kCTMessageIdKey = "-2147483636";
         kCTMessageTypeKey = 1; 
         */

        NSDictionary *info = (NSDictionary *)userInfo;
        CFNumberRef msgID = (CFNumberRef)info[@"kCTMessageIdKey"];
        int result;
        CFNumberGetValue((CFNumberRef)msgID, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &result);


         Class CTMessageCenter = NSClassFromString(@"CTMessageCenter");
         id mc = [CTMessageCenter sharedMessageCenter];
         id incMsg = [mc incomingMessageWithId: result];

         int msgType = (int)[incMsg messageType];

         if (msgType == 1) //experimentally detected number
         {
         id phonenumber = [incMsg sender];

         NSString *senderNumber = (NSString *)[phonenumber canonicalFormat];
         id incMsgPart = [incMsg items][0];
         NSData *smsData = [incMsgPart data];
         NSString *smsText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:smsData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

         }

    }
    else if ([notifyname isEqualToString:@"kCTIndicatorsSignalStrengthNotification"])//信号
    {
        /*
         kCTIndicatorsGradedSignalStrength = 2;
         kCTIndicatorsRawSignalStrength = "-101";
         kCTIndicatorsSignalStrength = 19;
         */

    }
    else if ([notifyname isEqualToString:@"kCTRegistrationStatusChangedNotification"])//网络注册状态
    {
        /*
         kCTRegistrationInHomeCountry = 1;
         kCTRegistrationStatus = kCTRegistrationStatusRegisteredHome;
         */

    }
    else if ([notifyname isEqualToString:@"kCTRegistrationDataStatusChangedNotification"])
    {
        /*
         kCTRegistrationDataActive = 1;
         kCTRegistrationDataAttached = 1;
         kCTRegistrationDataConnectionServices =     (
         kCTDataConnectionServiceTypeInternet,
         kCTDataConnectionServiceTypeWirelessModemTraffic,
         kCTDataConnectionServiceTypeWirelessModemAuthentication
         );
         kCTRegistrationDataContextID = 0;
         kCTRegistrationDataIndicator = kCTRegistrationDataIndicator3G;
         kCTRegistrationDataStatus = kCTRegistrationDataStatusAttachedAndActive;
         kCTRegistrationDataStatusInternationalRoaming = 1;
         kCTRegistrationRadioAccessTechnology = kCTRegistrationRadioAccessTechnologyUTRAN;
         */ 
    }
    else if ([notifyname isEqualToString:@"kCTRegistrationCellChangedNotification"])
    {
        /*
         kCTRegistrationGsmCellId = 93204174;
         kCTRegistrationGsmLac = 55583;
         kCTRegistrationInHomeCountry = 1;
         kCTRegistrationRadioAccessTechnology = kCTRegistrationRadioAccessTechnologyUTRAN; 
         */
    }
    else if ([notifyname isEqualToString:@"kCTIndicatorRadioTransmitNotification"])
    {
        /*
         kCTRadioTransmitDCHStatus = 1;
         */ 
    }
    //NSLog(@"名字:%@-详细:%@",notifyname,userInfo);


}

static void signalHandler(int sigraised)
{  
    NSLog(@"\nInterrupted.\n");  
    exit(0);  
}


@end
```

Comment: Did you found solution for this? I am facing the same issue. Please let me know, how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [ARC documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#objects.operands.casts) on the LLVM website. You'll have to use __bridge or one of the other keywords.

This is because Core Foundation objects (CF*Refs) are not controlled by ARC, only Obj-C objects are. So when you convert between them, you have to tell ARC about the object's ownership so it can properly clean them up. The simplest case is a __bridge cast, for which ARC will not do any extra work (it assumes you handle the object's memory yourself).